# TCP/IP Monitor to capture http calls from my localhost web server (hybris- tomcat) to remote web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat7, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to use eclipse TCP/IP Monitor to  capture http calls from my localhost web server (hybris- tomcat) to remote web service (REST calls) . So when I browse my local site (on same machine where the tomcat) I will be able to see (on the IDE) all the REST call going out from the application to the remote web services .
when using IDE TCP/IP Monitor - **what ports and host do I have to set**? I know the remote webservice I'm calling is listen on port 443 , and I see that the tomcat connector use port 8009 but how can I enforce the call to go through the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for monitoring http requests.